# Date 'wrap' in subtracting months

Tags: algorithm

What is a mathematical way of of saying 1 - 1 = 12 for a month calculation?  Adding is easy, 12 + 1 % 12 = 1, but subtraction introduces 0, stuffing things up.

My actual requirement is x = x + d, where x must always be between 1 and 12 before and after the summing, and d any unsigned integer.

Comment: In Python the solution I propose works for x = x + d (even for x = x - d), with the caveat that it'll be between 0 and 11. Don't know what are you working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd work internally with a 0 based month (0-11), summing one for external consumption only (output, another calling method expecting 1-12, etc.), that way you can wrap around backwards just as easily as wrapping around forward.

```
>>> for i in range(15):
...  print '%d + 1 => %d' % (i, (i+1)%12)
...
0 + 1 => 1
1 + 1 => 2
2 + 1 => 3
3 + 1 => 4
4 + 1 => 5
5 + 1 => 6
6 + 1 => 7
7 + 1 => 8
8 + 1 => 9
9 + 1 => 10
10 + 1 => 11
11 + 1 => 0
12 + 1 => 1
13 + 1 => 2
14 + 1 => 3
>>> for i in range(15):
...  print '%d - 1 => %d' % (i, (i-1)%12)
...
0 - 1 => 11
1 - 1 => 0
2 - 1 => 1
3 - 1 => 2
4 - 1 => 3
5 - 1 => 4
6 - 1 => 5
7 - 1 => 6
8 - 1 => 7
9 - 1 => 8
10 - 1 => 9
11 - 1 => 10
12 - 1 => 11
13 - 1 => 0
14 - 1 => 1
```

Comment: He did and later regretted it. It may have a problem in his platform. Would be nice to know though.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming x and y are both in the range 1-12:

```
((x - y + 11) % 12) + 1
```

To break this down:

```
// Range = [0, 22]
x - y + 11

// Range = [0, 11]
(x - y + 11) % 12

// Range = [1, 12]
((x - y + 11) % 12) + 1
```

Comment: What's the 'y'?  x + 11 as a surrogate for 'x - 1', modulo 12.

Comment: x is in 1-12, y can be anything

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with addition, too, since (11 + 1) % 12 = 0. Try this:

```
x % 12 + 1
```

This comes from using a normalisation function:

```
norm(x) = ((x - 1) % 12) + 1
```

Substituting,

```
norm(x + 1) = (((x + 1) - 1) % 12 + 1

norm(x + 1) = (x) % 12 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The % (modulus) operator produces an answer in the range 0..(N-1) for x % N.  Given that your inputs are in the range 1..N (for N = 12), the general adding code for adding a positive number y months to current month x should be:

```
(x + y - 1) % 12 + 1
```

When y is 1, this reduces to

```
x % 12 + 1
```

Subtracting is basically the same.  However, there are complications with the answers produced by different implementations of the modulus operator when either (or both) of the operands is negative.  If the number to be subtracted is known to be in in the range 1..N, then you can use the fact that subtracting y modulo N is the same as adding (N - y) modulo N.  If y is unconstrained (but positive), then use:

```
(x + (12 - (y % 12) - 1) % 12 + 1
```

This double-modulo operation is a common part of the solution to problems like this when the range of the values is not under control.